# I can't upgrade my OS until I change my icloud drives settings

Tags: macos, icloud, mac-appstore

I have an Apple 2011 laptop. I haven't done any recent updates and nor have I downloaded anything either. My computer needs to upgrade to the next OS but it is saying that a change has to be made to my iCloud settings before I can use my App Store. I have no idea what this could mean.

I tried upgrading my credit card info on my Apple account and rebooting the laptop, to no avail. I also deselected some of the items in iCloud, but to be really honest am less familiar with Macs than PCs.

What do I need to do so I can upgrade my Mac?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Unfortunately, your question doesn't provide enough detail for us to help you. Reading [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting a good answer. For now, can you please edit your question (there's an edit link below it) to add info such as: (1) What version of macOS you're currently on? (2) The exact error message you're getting? (3) Anything else you feel could be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides free support for basic use of the Mac App Store and basic iCloud support, so I would start with them.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201541
- https://support.apple.com/icloud

Once you have some expert help on narrowing down what specifically you need to change / opt in / enable on your iCloud / Apple ID - then you will be able to see what / why you can't use the Mac App Store to download a new update. You probably have a few bridges to cross so try to pick apart specific messages and error conditions or specific things you can't find online if you ask a follow on question here.